# Accessing Text File from Service

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe7

I'm tryin to write a simple service in Delphi XE7, in a Win7 64bit virtual machine where Delphi is installed.
All what i need for now is to open/create a text file and write something into it every second. It should be simple ... should ...

Immediately after creating the service, and installing it, it runs well.
I addedd this code:

```
const
  LogName = 'C:\GFLog.txt';

var FLogFile : TextFile;

procedure TServiceTest.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);

begin
  ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
  try
    AssignFile(FLogFile, LogName);
    if not FileExists(LogName)
      then Append(FlogFile)
      else Rewrite(FlogFile);
    WriteLn(FLogFile,'Start '+TimeToStr(Now));

    while not Terminated do
    begin
      WriteLn(FLogFile,TimeToStr(Now));
      Sleep(1000);
      ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
    end;

    CloseFile(FLogFile);
  except
    on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message)
  end;
end;
```

As a result, the file is not created, no errors are shown, and I can't understand why.
Of course, I've made something wrong, but what?

Someone can help?

Comment: OT: I think it's time to consider contacting Delphi tutorial servers to update their content. The Pascal I/O file access that can be seen so many times is disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved ... copy and paste error ... i feelVERY stupid, but ...

```
if not FileExists(LogName)
  then Append(FlogFile)
  else Rewrite(FlogFile);
```

I was tryin to append to not exixting file ...